# The user can input many numbers as they like and will stop if they will enter zero then get the sum of all the numbers they have entered

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int num=0;
    int total=0;

    cout<<"Enter many numbers as you like : "<<endl;

    while (cin>>num){
     if (num==0){
        break;
        cout<<"The sum is : " ;
        total = total + num;

     }

    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this it runs and when I enter zero the program stops but it did not get the sum of the numbers entered by the user. please help me with this problem. thanks. :)

Comment: Not seeing a question.

Comment: You should do total in ELSE `total = total + num;` and you should `break;` loop after `cout<<"The sum is : " << total << endl;` this statement.

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged the program?

Answer (score 0):

To print a number do:

```
cout<<"The sum is : " << total << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to place the`break;` statement as the last line of your conditional `if(...){...}` statement. When the program reaches the `break`statement, it will exit the while loop and proceed to the end of the program. Right now your loop is exited before `cout` has the new stream written to it and the total is updated.

Second, you want to put the value of total on the output stream:

```
cout << "The sum is : " << total << endl;
```

Currently, you are just printing out the string `"The sum is :"`

Also, `system("PAUSE");` is a shell and OS dependent statement, and usually not seen as good coding practice. You may want to look into another way to accomplish this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/30581-holding-the-execution-window-open/